# ESP8266 not connecting to django server

Tags: python, django, httprequest, esp8266

I've created a local server on my pc with django and im trying to send a GET request from my esp8266 01 module which just gives a message and a POST request which send data that is stored in a JSON file.
The server works fine with postman but doesnt connect with a esp.

The http request gives error code -1
This is code only for GET
ESP Code:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFiMulti.h>
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>

ESP8266WiFiMulti WiFiMulti;

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(115200);
  // Serial.setDebugOutput(true);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();

  for (uint8_t t = 4; t > 0; t--) {
    Serial.printf("[SETUP] WAIT %d...\n", t);
    Serial.flush();
    delay(1000);
  }

  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFiMulti.addAP("username", "password");

}

void loop() {
  // wait for WiFi connection
  if ((WiFiMulti.run() == WL_CONNECTED)) {

    WiFiClient client;

    HTTPClient http;

    Serial.print("[HTTP] begin...\n");
    if (http.begin(client, "http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/")) { 


      Serial.print("[HTTP] GET...\n");
      // start connection and send HTTP header
      int httpCode = http.GET();

      // httpCode will be negative on error
      if (httpCode > 0) {
        // HTTP header has been send and Server response header has been handled
        Serial.printf("[HTTP] GET... code: %d\n", httpCode);

        // file found at server
        if (httpCode == HTTP_CODE_OK || httpCode == HTTP_CODE_MOVED_PERMANENTLY) {
          String payload = http.getString();
          Serial.println(payload);
        }
      } else {
        Serial.printf("[HTTP] GET... failed, error: %s\n", http.errorToString(httpCode).c_str());
      }

      http.end();
    } else {
      Serial.printf("[HTTP} Unable to connect\n");
    }
  }

  delay(10000);
}
```

polls/views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
from django.http import HttpResponse, JsonResponse
import json
from django.conf import settings

User_id = ""
pID = ""
DB = settings.DB_FILE

def readDB(filename=DB):
    with open(filename, mode='r') as jsonFile:
        data = json.load(jsonFile)

    return data

def writeDB(object, filename=DB):
    with open(filename, mode='r') as jsonFile:
        data = json.load(jsonFile)
        data["uid"] = object

    with open(filename, mode="w") as f:
        json.dump(data,f)




def index(request):
    if(request.method == 'GET'):
        return HttpResponse("The url was wrong......so there's nothing we can do:(")

    elif(request.method =='POST'):
        obj = json.loads(request.body)
        User_id = obj["uid"]
        writeDB(object = User_id)
        return HttpResponse(User_id)

def getID(request):
    if(request.method == 'GET'):
        return HttpResponse("The url was wrong......so there's nothing we can do:(")

    elif(request.method =='POST'):
        obj = json.loads(request.body)
        pID = obj["uid"]
        User_id = readDB()
        if pID == User_id["uid"]:
            return JsonResponse({"Status":"Verified"})
        else :
            return JsonResponse({"Status":"Galat"})
```

polls/url.py:

```
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('getID/', views.getID, name='inde'),
]
```

mysite/urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include,path

urlpatterns = [
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

mysite/settings.py:

```
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-5p4@fan0vy$+=*e063#3xfmr78z5c#i12gjp$+%27g8a!sulur'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'corsheaders',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    # 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
DB_FILE = "./db.json"

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

Comment: If you are running that on a different device, the URL is not going to be `http://127.0.0.1:8000`. Make sure Django is listening to external connections and enter the real IP of the server into the URL.

Comment: Could u elaborate a little bit more i am new at this

Comment: you need to enter the ip address of the PC hosting the server, if its windows you enter the ip that you get when running the ipconfig cmd command